# DefineProperty method is undefined in object created via constructor

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor for parent:

```
function genshinImpactCharacter(weapon, vision, rarity) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.vision = vision;
    this.rarity = rarity;
}
```

Later I create an object with the `new` keyword:

```
const Sucrose = new genshinImpactCharacter('Catalyst', 'Anemo', 4);
```

I am trying to use defineProperty to add property `favFlower: "Sweet Flower"`

```
Object.defineProperty(Sucrose, "favFlower", {
    name: 'Sweet Flower',
});
```

However, when I am trying to access `favFlower`, it returns `undefined`. As well, when I print the whole object in the console, this property remains `undefined`.

Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: If you don't mind the property been mutated, in the same way `weapon` etc can be, why not just do `Sucrose.favFlower = 'Sweet Flower'`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the property `enumerable` (which defaults to `false`) to see it when inspecting the object. Also you want to set `value` of the property, not `name`:

```js
function genshinImpactCharacter(weapon, vision, rarity) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.vision = vision;
    this.rarity = rarity;
}

const Sucrose = new genshinImpactCharacter('Catalyst', 'Anemo', 4);

Object.defineProperty(Sucrose, 'favFlower', {
    value: 'Sweet Flower',
    enumerable: true,
});

console.log(Sucrose);
```

Please also note that by default properties added with `Object.defineProperty()` are not `writable` (`writable: false` again is the default), so with the current code you cannot assign to the property later. Trying to do so will fail silently in non-strict mode, and throw an error in strict mode.

As a last note, by default properties added with `Object.defineProperty()` are not `configurable` (`configurable: false` again is the default), so with the current code you cannot `delete` the property or change it using `Object.defineProperty()` on that object with the same property name again. Trying to do so will fail silently in non-strict mode, and throw an error in strict mode.

For more information, please consult https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: Thank you a lot! Somehow, I decided that "value" may be replaced by the user's choice, but it would make no sense. As well, thanks for mentioning the enumerable property.